# Unknown error in sqldf package

Tags: r, sqldf, rsqlite

What does this error mean?

```
Closing open result set, pending rowsError in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

This appears when i want to run the code

````
    ```{r}
    library(sqldf)
    first <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname= "DATA.sqlite")

    dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
                "CREATE TABLE COMPANY_MASTER
                ( 
    CompId INTEGER,
    CompName TEXT,
    Address TEXT,
    DirectorName TEXT,
    EmployeeNo INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(CompName)
                )")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
                VALUES(1001,'Infosys','ABC1927','Dr.Sandeep',128)")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
                VALUES(1002,'Cognizant','ERT654','Michael',156)")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
                VALUES(1003,'Tata','PCD531','Sancheti',113)")
    *

dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
                "CREATE TABLE INCOME
                ( 
    CompName TEXT,
    In(2016) INTEGER,
    In(2017) INTEGER,
    In(2018) INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(CompName)

*
                )")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
                VALUES('518361','528464','538646')")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
                VALUES('218434','205314','225815')")
    dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
                VALUES('1038434','1184344','128434')")
    CompMAst <- dbGetQuery(conn = first, "SELECT * FROM COMPANY_MASTER")
    Income <- dbGetQuery(conn = first, "SELECT * FROM INCOME")
    ```
````

While giving the above error in the

```
dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
            "CREATE TABLE INCOME
            ( 
CompName TEXT,
In(2016) INTEGER,
In(2017) INTEGER,
In(2018) INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(CompName)
            )")
```

region of the code. What does this error mean? Is it some specific format error? Or have i missed some chunk that had to be mentioned before executing. Or is some other package involved Please help.

Comment: gives error Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near ")": syntax error

Comment: `dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
            "CREATE TABLE INCOME
            ( 
CompName TEXT,
In_2016 INTEGER,
In_2017 INTEGER,
In_2018 INTEGER
            )")`

Comment: But why does the foreign key give the error? Is it not applicable here? What if i want to use joins or other queries later? @SatZ

Comment: This code is only using functions from the RSQLite package, nothing from sqldf itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @SatZ and the error of you giving four columns and entering three values your ideal code should be

````
```{r}
library(sqldf)
first <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname= "DATA.sqlite")

dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
            "CREATE TABLE COMPANY_MASTER
            ( 
CompId INTEGER,
CompName TEXT,
Address TEXT,
DirectorName TEXT,
EmployeeNo INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(CompName)
            )")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
            VALUES(1001,'Infosys','ABC1927','Dr.Sandeep',128)")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
            VALUES(1002,'Cognizant','ERT654','Michael',156)")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO COMPANY_MASTER
            VALUES(1003,'Tata','PCD531','Sancheti',113)")
dbSendQuery(conn =  first,
            "CREATE TABLE INCOME
            ( 
CompName TEXT,
IN_2016 TEXT,
IN_2017 TEXT,
IN_2018 TEXT)")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
            VALUES('Infosys','5183.61','5284.64','5386.46')")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
            VALUES('Cognizant','2184.34','2053.14','2258.15')")
dbSendQuery(conn = first, "INSERT INTO INCOME
            VALUES('Tata','10384.34','11843.44','1284.34')")
CompMAst <- dbGetQuery(conn = first, "SELECT * FROM COMPANY_MASTER")
Income <- dbGetQuery(conn = first, "SELECT * FROM INCOME")
```
````

Comment: Why does removal of foreign key aid the problem. And thanks for the column and data entering error.

Answer (score 0):

The `dbSendQuery()` method returns a `"DBIResult"` object, it's the caller's responsibility to clear it with `dbClearResult()`. For queries that don't return a result set, use `dbExecute()` instead of `dbSendQuery()` to avoid the warning. (`dbExecute()` is the equivalent of `dbGetQuery()` for queries that don't return a result set.)

See the help to `dbBind()` for use cases of the longer form `dbSendQuery()` + `dbFetch()` + `dbClearResult()`.